# Several PHP pages with processing in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm currently setting up a Drupal website with localization which works pretty well. But today I'm confronted with a situation for which I don't see a clear solution. I've been googling around and sniffing through the Drupal forums to find the correct way to solve this situation but I can't find a solid solution.

In my website I have a page that contains a search form, the user can input a zip code or a breed of a dog/cat. But the hard thing about it is that the data needs to come from an external service. So, no fancy drupal CCK datatypes, views or whatsoever.

So I was wondering what the correct way is to implement some custom php code. What I exactly mean: I need to implement several php scripts that were already programmed by someone else. Think about it like this: someone made a php file with a html form in it, when the user clicks the search button you get redirected to results.php which show the results of the search query in a list.

So, I'm wondering what the best way is to implement such a custom code without rewriting the whole thing (it's a lot more complex than the stripped down case I'm talking about here, so a complete rewrite isn't a solution at the moment).

Should I make a custom content type and put php code in a seperate .tpl.php file?
Should I enable the PHP module and start putting in php code in the body field of a page? But what about communicating data over several pages? And so on, ... ?

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the following:

- Build a new search module from the php scripts
- Build a second module to override the default search form so the search is handled by your module, not core search

For a good starting point, take a look at the Apache Solr Search module from Drupal.org 
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

Bonus points for making it a "live" search with Ajax 
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_ajax

Comment: I'm going to vote your solution up because it is probably the cleanest, but the development time would be longer which I don't have at the moment. Apart from that I need to include other php scripts that don't have to do with search functionality. Meaning, I need a more general approach for embedding custom php/sql. I read something about making .tpl.php files with a specific node id?

Comment: Adding node-id-specific .tpl files is a really,really bad idea. Without knowing the specifics of the scripts you're talking about I can't really give you a good answer on this. But generally speaking, if you want to integrate external applications without doing it the Drupal way (modules) then maybe you should really look into doing it via Ajax. That way you only have to make your scripts return JSON and all interfacing could be done via JavaScript which is easily injected with the drupal_add_js call. From then on you can manipulate the DOM all you want without having to mess with Drupal.